# My SQL; You have error in your SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql

[image: The table Book_Details is described here :-]

[image: This is the Category_Details Table :-]

[image: This is the Binding_Details Table :-]

i dont understand what the syntax error is ?

Comment: `insert into <table name>`... not `insert into table <table name>`.

Comment: And use single quotes for strings, not double quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the Mysql documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

The syntax of your insert query is incorrect.
You have `insert into table SOMETABLE(column1, column2,...`

This must be like `insert into SOMETABLE (column1, column2...) VALUES (...`

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the keyword TABLE in your insert query. Then it will work fine